# GCP Custom IAM role creation with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create a custom IAM role in GCP with Terraform for my instances. AFIACT, the follow should work, but yet it errors out on me, complaining that the standard roles I want to include are not valid.

```
resource "google_project_iam_custom_role" "my-instance-role" {
  role_id     = "myInstanceRole"
  title       = "My Instance Role"
  description = "my custom iam role"
  permissions = [
    "roles/storage.objectCreator", 
    "roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypter"
  ]
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
* google_project_iam_custom_role.my-instance-role: Error creating 
the custom project role My Instance Role: googleapi: Error 400: 
Permission roles/storage.objectCreator is not valid., badRequest
```

The Terraform docs aren't super clear, but from what I've read, this should work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out. You can't include a [predefined GCP role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined_roles) in a custom role. You have to specify the [specific service permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#viewing_the_available_permissions_for_a_resource). What I really wanted to do was this:

```
resource "google_project_iam_custom_role" "my-instance-role" {
  role_id     = "myInstanceRole"
  title       = "My Instance Role"
  description = "my custom iam role"
  permissions = [
    "storage.objects.create", 
    "cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.useToEncrypt"
  ]
}
```

The key here is the difference between predefined GCP roles such as "roles/storage.objectCreator" which is a collection of GCP permissions and using those individual permissions on their own. When creating a custom IAM role in Terraform, you must specify the individual service level permissions you want to apply, such as "storage.objects.create".

Comment: The answer seems incomplete, is it an extension to the question (in that case edit the question), or is it an incompletely described solution? And then accept your own answer so we know it's solved.

Comment: Sorry, this is a complete answer and I have accepted it as such.

Comment: I've edited my answer to hopefully provide more clarity. Please let me know what you think is missing.

Comment: You can get that list of predefined items using: `gcloud iam roles describe roles/storage.objectCreator`
includedPermissions:
- orgpolicy.policy.get
- resourcemanager.projects.get
- resourcemanager.projects.list
- storage.multipartUploads.abort
- storage.multipartUploads.create
- storage.multipartUploads.listParts
- storage.objects.create
...

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are giving roles in permission section which is wrong.
You can use some modules which allows you to create a custom roles using set of pre-define roles and permissions. You can use or refer my code here - [Terraform code to create custom roles](https://github.com/indrajitp/terraform-gcp-custom-roles.git)

Note : All permissions do not work with custom role, So for example if you are trying to give `roles/iam.securityAdmin` role then you will have to exclude some permission since they are not allowed in custom roles. You will have to make a list of exclude permission manually since there is no way around.
[image]

This is how you will have to list down all roles which needs to be excluded.
Just pass this to module like this -

```
module "custom-viewer-role-project" {
  #count = length(var.viewer_permissions)
  source = "../../modules/custom_role_iam/"
  target_level         = "project"
  target_id            = var.project_id
  role_id              = var.viewer_role_id
  base_roles           = var.viewer_base_roles
  permissions          = var.viewer_permissions
  excluded_permissions = var.viewer_excluded_permissions
  description          = var.viewer_description
  members              = ["serviceAccount:${var.viewer_members}@${var.project_id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"]
}
```

Variables -
viewer_base_roles = Here you list down all your roles needed

viewer_excluded_permissions = Here you will have to provide list of exclude permissions